# How can I show task approvers comment to next level approver

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, tasks

When a task is approved that task have some comment and that comment is useful for the next level of the approver.
I want to show that comment to next level of the approver while he want to take action on that task.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a column in the associated work flow task list, call it "comments".
2. Create a workflow variable also name it "comments".
3. Use "Assign a Task" to assign the task to Approver 1, reason being this action can provide you GUID of the assigned task.
4. set workflow variable "Comments" to Task list  comments 
   A.Data source will be Task list
   B. Field form source will be: comments 
   C. Return field as: plain text
   D. Field: GUID
   F. Value: TaskID

In the associated email of 2nd approver use this work flow variable to show him the comments.